# how to use CreateView? django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: django/forms/widgets/text.html

Tags: python

I want to use CreateView.
But,it generates the error django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist:django/forms/widgets/text.html

root/accounting_report/views.py

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from .models import AccountingReport
class ReportCreateView(CreateView):
    model = AccountingReport
    fields = ['name','receipts','expenses','user_id']
    success_url="accounting_report/"
```

root/accounting_report/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from accounting_report.views import ReportCreateView
urlpatterns = [
    path('create', ReportCreateView.as_view(), name='accountingreport_form'),
```

toot/templates/accounting_report/accountingreport_form.html
{{  form  }}　had a　Error during template rendering

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="ja">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{  form  }}
    <button type="submit">save</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `ReportCreateView`:

```
template_name = "accounting_report/accountingreport_form.html"
```